# How to show Query result Activerecord Query Interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have а little question, write through Activerecord Query Interface
It's actually:

`Gp.select("date('gps'.'created_at') as date,('users'.'name') as name, SUM('gps'.'sum_issue') as sum_issue").joins('LEFT  JOIN users  ON users.id = gps.user_id').where("users.ab_id = :abs_id  AND users.id != 20", {:abs_id => current_user.ab_id}).group("users.name")`

Result of query must be user name, sum,and date. If i do this query directly from SQLlite it's work, But 
Active Record Query Interface give me

```
[#<Gp sum_issue: 289000>, #<Gp sum_issue: 364130>, #<Gp sum_issue: 620000>]
```

How i can get a name,date,sum_issue and show it in my helper.
like this:

```
{
 created_at: datet,
 sum_issue: sum_issue,
 name: name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Gp.select("date('gps'.'created_at') as date,('users'.'name') as name, SUM('gps'.'sum_issue') as sum_issue").joins('LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = gps.user_id').where("users.ab_id = :abs_id AND users.id != 20", {:abs_id => current_user.ab_id}).group("users.name").first.name
```

Comment: Thank you, but this query return only name of person. I want that query return name, sum_issue and date. Than i want transform data in JSON format.Like
   {
    created_at: date,
    sum_issue: sum_issue,
   }

Comment: remove name from the end of this "spagetti". When you perform group method, it returns objects with all columns, declared in your select. But in console the result is displayed with aggregated columns only. If you want to serialize this array to json, try `Gp.select(...).joins(...).where(...).group(...).to_json`, and you'll see your date, name, and sum.

Comment: Ok it's work and how i can iterate format JSON (map,each dosn't work)

Comment: `arr=[]; Gp.select(...).joins(...).where(...).group(...).each { |result| arr << result.to_json}; puts arr`